# Can a black hole absorb linear momentum?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, momentum, conservation-laws

I know that black holes maintain the linear momentum of the object that created it. But if I throw a baseball into a black hole, will it absorb that momentum as well?

I think the answer has to be "yes" because momentum needs to be conserved, but I am having trouble getting my head around how a black hole can react to momentum.

Comment: Why would you expect a black hole to "react" to momentum any differently from the way any other massive object reacts? Of course, if you pitch a baseball into a black hole whose mass is several times the mass of our Sun, you might have a hard time measuring the resulting change in the BH's velocity.

Comment: Guessing that the question is about how a black hole could absorb momentum.  With a normal solid-body, an impactor could hit it to transfer momentum to the rest of the body (even if it sticks after that in an inelastic collision).  But with a black-hole, does something "_impacting_" it necessarily hit anything?  Or pass by the center-of-mass?  Seems like a question about how momentum would be conserved.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is imagining an impactor falling into a black-hole, then experiencing infinite time-dilation, such that, for all of eternity, the impactor never crosses the center-of-mass nor physically contacts anything, such that the impactor's gravitational pull ends up pulling the black-hole in the direction of the impactor's approach, apparently contradicting the conservation-of-linear-momentum.  (Is this a correct interpretation?)

Comment: @Marc DiNino Seems to me if the BH _didn't_ "absorb" the momentum, the baseball would need to emerge on the other side (or bounce off I suppose).  Neither is possible.

Comment: @Nat You are correct. That is why I am confused.

Comment: Discussion on the first page of ["_Understanding the "anti-kick" in the merger of binary black holes_"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.0873) (2010), in relationship to its $\text{Fig. 1} ,$ looks interesting.  ["_Gravitational-Radiation Recoil and Runaway Black Holes_"](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1973ApJ...183..657B) (1973) and [this from 1962](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.128.2471)  look like the earlier works.  [Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_black_hole#Black-hole_merger_recoil).  Most of the stuff's about binary black holes.

Comment: In short it looks like it's well-accepted that black holes don't locally conserve linear momentum upon collisions but rather radiate it through gravitational waves.  Apparently the kick's powerful enough that the literature has a lot of discussion about ejecting supermassive black holes from their host galaxies.. which, hah, wow.  Presumably you'd be looking at a smaller version of this, as one of the impactors presumably isn't a black hole.

Comment: @Nat I'd like this to be the accepted answer

Comment: [A recent study](https://vijayvarma392.github.io/GW200129/) ([related paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.01302)) has [a neat animation](https://vijayvarma392.github.io/GW200129/movies/GW200129.mp4) of a kick inferred from a merger.

Answer (score 2):

Black hole will absorb the momentum and start to move with a constant speed.

A black hole solution can be transformed to any other inertial frame via a global Lorentz transformation, so it can move with any speed through space.